# FTP passive mode in PHP

Tags: php, ftp

Need to set at FTP connection in passive mode in a PHP file.

Not sure how to do it when my connection details is the following:

```
protected $_credentials = array (
    'host'      => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
    'user'      => 'xxxxx',
    'password'  => 'xxxxx',
    'timeout'   => '10'
    );
```

How do I add the passive mode to the above?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you use [built-in PHP FTP functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php) (`ftp_*`), use [`ftp_pasv` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php), like:

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($host) or die("Unable to connect to host");

ftp_login($conn_id, $user, $password) or die("Authorization failed");

// turn passive mode on
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true) or die("Unable switch to passive mode");
```

---

*Your code sample only creates an associative array. It does not really do any "FTP". So if you are using a different PHP FTP library, you will have to tell us.*